# Is there any better approach to pass data to child without stateful, inherited widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

**I've a class like below,**

```
class DottedLine extends StatelessWidget{
  final double circleSize, space;
  final Color color;

  DottedLine({@required this.color, this.circleSize = 1.0, this.space = 5.0});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return CustomPaint(painter: _DottedLinePainter(color: color, circleSize: circleSize, space: space),);
  }

}
```

**And another class is,**

```
class _DottedLinePainter extends CustomPainter{

  _DottedLinePainter({this.color, this.circleSize, this.space});

  final double circleSize, space;
  final Color color;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size){
  ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Here, from **DottedLine** I'm passing the same three-parameter to the **_DottedLinePainter** Now If I want to add a new parameter for the class **_DottedLinePainter**, I've to create it for **DottedLine** too...

So how can define the parameter name in one place only? But I don't want to extends Inherited Widgets cause if I do, then it foreces me to change **DottedLine** StatefulWidget which is unneccessary.

Comment: What about using [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)?

Comment: I don't want it to be a Stateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reduce duplication by directly passing the widget to your custom painter, instead of passing the widget's property:

```dart
class DottedLine extends StatelessWidget{
  final double circleSize, space;
  final Color color;

  DottedLine({@required this.color, this.circleSize = 1.0, this.space = 5.0});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return CustomPaint(painter: _DottedLinePainter(this),);
  }
}

class _DottedLinePainter extends CustomPainter{

  _DottedLinePainter(this.data);

  final DottedLine data;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size){
  ...
  }
  ...
}
```